# Obtaining wifi IP address

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

Im messing around with security, its all new to me. I have installed hydro on my pc and a wifi router in the other room. I can easily crack it knowing my routers ip. If I didnt know the ip, what would I need to do to obtain it, meaning.. how can I get it to self Identify and is it as simple as using windows to connect to the hotspot, waiting for a prompt asking for a user/pw then run somthing to self identify its ip? Id love to know if anyone can help.

Answer (score 3):

In the majority of domestic scenarios, and many small business environments, the wireless AP you are connected to is also the default gateway.

So from Windows, you can just use

```
route print
```

from a command line.  You'll see a line like:

```
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.31.96.1    10.31.96.158       10
```

The gateway IP address is the wireless AP that you have connected to.

In more complex environments, as establishing a wifi connection is effectively ISO layer 1, it isn't possible to easily identify the IP address of the AP. At least it is no different to attempting to work out the IP address of a switch with which you may have a wired connection.  It may not even have an IP on the network you are connected to.